# Mapfile generation from QGIS project

Tags: qgis, mapserver, qgis-2, mapfile

I am looking for a way to transform a QGIS project (.qgs) to a MapServer Mapfile (.map).

I am using Quantum GIS 2.6 and MapServer 6.

The layers are postgis tables.

I would need something like this but it is not being displayed in my QGIS plugins list: http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/es/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_mapserver_export.html

Instead it only shows this plugin: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/rt_mapserver_exporter/ but does not seem to convert qgs to mapfile.

Any solution to this?

Comment: Could you clarify what's wrong with RT Mapserver Exporter? Based on the description it seems to do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: As far as I tested, it generates a mapfile giving a SHP file, but not of the whole .qgs project

Comment: as far as I know RT_Mapserver_Exporter (I ported it to 2.x) if convert the entire project with some limitation in styling due the fact that it use the mapscript/sld interface to convert the project style in mapfile style... and qgis styling is richer than that exposed by sld. But it should work.